# Removed MY_APP.app file

Tags: iphone, filesystems, xcode4.1

I moved `MY_APP.app` file by mistake, in Xcode Project Navigator, under "products" folder, it seems red now, what will be the consequences?

And how can I bring it back?

When I build and run the project in iPhone simulator it doesn't come back.

Answer (score 0):

Delete the red marked file(which means that is not located physically).Reset the simulator and clean all targets. Build first and then run should work.

Comment: hi thank you for your answer. but i deleted the .app file and cleaned the project and rebuilt it and ran it. the simulator closed itself.

Comment: Why? are you getting any crash?